# Undeclared selector warnining in ios 7

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, selector, nstimer

I'm tying create a welcome label using `NSTimer` but its showing the through some warnings

like

> undeclared selector hidelable and unused variable timer

I have not used the `NSTimer` before can one pls tell me where im doing wrong and wt is the  right method to do it.I need to give a welcome message when app load after few minities it has to disappear

i have tried this one im not able to get pls help me

this is the code i have to used in the view didload

```
NSTimer  * timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60 target:self selector:@selector(hideLabel:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

in storyboard i have used ib label which i want to display message

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *wel;
```

please any one tell wt is proper way to make this one..

Comment: where is your method definition for `hideLabel:` ?

Comment: Please paste the real and full error message including proper case and punctuation. You are dealing with programming. Being precise is critical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have not declared hideLabel method.hence it gives that warning

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60 target:self selector:@selector(hideLabel:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

-(void)hideLabel:(NSTimer *)timer{
 myLabel.hidden=YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.3 target:self selector:@selector(timerCalled) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    -(void)timerCalled
    {
         NSLog(@"Timer Called...");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your code, You didn't use timer anywhere else, and didn't fire repeatedly. Then you can use this code as below..

```
[self performSelector:@selector(hideLabel:) withObject:yourLabel afterDelay:60];
```

Importantly, define your target method,

```
-(void)hideLabel:(UILabel*)label
{
    // your code here...
     label.text = @"Fired...";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you does not need to use *(extra use of)* object of `NSTimer`  then you should create `NSTimer` such like,

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60.0f    target:self selector:@selector(hideLabel:) userInfo:nil    repeats:NO];
```

And then you need to declare timer's method other wise after active *(60 sec.)* timer you will be get error.

```
- (void)hideLabel:(NSTimer *)theTimer
{
   // Timer method code;
}
```